# gcd of two polynomials using euclidean algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra

Using the Euclidean algorithm, I need to find the gcd. I believe it needs to be a linear combination, but I honestly don't understand how to find it.

So ($x^4+x^3+2x^2+x-1$)-(something)$\cdot (x^3+1$) I believe but I don't know how to find the something

Comment: Hint: try values of (something) that make (something)$\cdot(x^3+1)$ have an $x^4$ term...

Comment: @abiessu maybe $(x+1)$? Then I get $x^4+x^3+x+1$. So I would end up with $2x^2-2$ as a remainder. Does this seem right?

Comment: $$x^4+x^3+2 x^2+x-1=(x+1) \left(x^3+2 x-1\right);\;x^3+1=(x+1) \left(x^2-x+1\right)$$
I'd say that GCD is $x+1$

Comment: Do you know polynomial long division?

Comment: @rogerl yes, where should I use it?

Comment: You can use it in each step of the Euclidean algorithm: for example, in the first step, you get $x^4+x^3+2x^2+x-1 = q(x)(x^3+1) + r(x)$ where the degree of $r(x)$ is at most $2$. Then continue as usual with the Euclidean algorithm.